# Django Rest API Unit Testing returning 401 Unauthorized for endpoint tests

Tags: python, django, api, rest, unit-testing

I created some unit tests with basic asserts checking for status codes to get a few tests done and working. The endpoints themselves work flawlessly when I test them individually outside of the Django unit tests using `manage.py test test_file`
However, I am getting a 401 Unauthorized on all endpoints when I run the tests. I have tried writing in several auth methods to correct the issue but no matter what I try, a 401 is returned.

I have tried adding a force auth function, changing `TestCase` to `APITestCase`, and creating a superuser manually in the `setUp()` for each of my test cases.
All of the solutions I have found online for similar problems still yield the 401, unauthorized error.

Using:

Django 3.2.14

Python 3.10.4

I have also followed the Django Rest API documentation for test cases to the letter.
I get 401 errors all the way through.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send jwt tokens in unit test

get jwt tokens and call like this

```
response = self.client.post("path", {}, Authorization='Bearer ' + token)
```